# Best way to display category description on first page only

Tags: category

What is the best way to only show the category description on the first page of a category?

I found the following way but not sure if it is the best:

```
 <?php $currentPage = (int) Mage::App()->getRequest()->getParam('p'); 
    if($currentPage <= 1): ?>
        <div class="category-description std">              <div class="category-description std">
            <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>                 <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
        </div>              </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried it? If it works is the best.

Comment: In which  file,have you done the changes?

Comment: itmay be spelling mistake `Mage::App()->getRequest()->getParam('p') to Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('p')`

Comment: The code above works.  I'm just not sure if it is the most optimal way to go about doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do this in Magento 2 (2.4.3) and also removing the description from all of the filtered pages.